# Trying to center element and force scroll

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make this page responsive and keep the grey background part centralized without messing up the page view on resize. Please help this is my CSS.

What I am trying to get (But scrolling):
http://www.nzservers.ml/indexa.html

What is not working and zooming in on resize, when adding more content:
http://www.nzservers.ml/indexa.html

CSS and HTML:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-image: url(matrix.gif), url(background.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat, no-repeat;
    background-size: auto, cover;
    padding-top: 15px;
    font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}

html, body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#container {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;-moz-border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px; height:55%; width:65%; border:4px solid #2a2830;background-color:#2a2830;
    opacity: .9;
    box-shadow:2px 2px 7px #2B2B2B;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<body bgcolor="#000000">
    <div id="container">
        
        <h2 class="unknowen">Unknowen.<span class="dev">dev</span></h2>
        <p class="mainText">If you know who I am, good for you. I am also a self-trained web designer and hobbyist game developer.</p>
        <p class="mainText"></p>
        <p class="mainText"></p>

        <h2 class="mySites">mySites</h2>

        <div class="items">
            <a href="#" class="item" title="MySite01">
            <div>
                <img src="img/emptyButton.png" alt="MySite01" class="img">
            </div>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="item" title="MySite01">
                <div>
                    <img src="img/emptyButton.png" alt="MySite01" class="img">
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="item" title="MySite01">
                <div>
                    <img src="img/emptyButton.png" alt="MySite01" class="img">
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="copyrightBox">
        <p class="mainText"><span class="copy">&copy;</span> Copyright</p>
    </div>
    
</body>
```

Thank you :)

Comment: provide a minimal reproducible code snippet (ctrl + m) inluding all necessary elements (html + css). CSS lines without coressponding HTML are meaningless.

Comment: @tacoshy like so?